# Change google maps api key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

I'm faced with problem with google maps.
App has already uploaded into store. Also account lost with access to console. So, I make update for app and create new api key and added fingerprints for both release and debug versions. 
Generated apk works correct, but after I'm upload and publish update, maps not working and console has log:

```
In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com                                                          Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                   Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                    API Key: AIzaSyAEtaL_6qG1Fri5K3K**********
                                                                                    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 3B:96:BB:F4:9D:13:86:C8:2:******
```

What I forgot do, to correct change api key ? How to solve it ?

Comment: Did you [enable](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158841) **Google Maps Android API**?

Comment: @gar_r sure, I'm enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking and experiment some times. I found the reason.
I'm use android studio tool to generate apk.
Arter remove

> signingConfigs

section from build.gradle of my app module, it begin works. Maybe will be useful for someone. Thanks.